# Checking previous and current value of values within a list by For loop

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, for-loop

I want to make a function within the for loop that checks the current `y` value
and compares if it is greater or lower than the previous `y` value. If it is I want the code to `print("red")`.

```
x_long = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
L_Amount_list = [100.00, 9313.38, 43601.28, 61701.69, 74331.88, 198913.81, 153054.54, 119162.10, 74382.25, 203542.82, 160774.71, 220307.19, 366459.26]
for x,y in zip(x_long,L_Amount_list):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x_long = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
L_Amount_list = [100.00, 9313.38, 43601.28, 61701.69, 74331.88, 198913.81, 153054.54, 119162.10, 74382.25, 203542.82, 160774.71, 220307.19, 366459.26]
for index, group in enumerate(zip(x_long,L_Amount_list)):
    if group[1] > L_Amount_list[index - 1]:
        print("red")
```